# C# UWP MediaPlayer crash on emulator

Tags: c#, crash, uwp

I'm new to UWP, and i tried instantinate MediaPlayer class. On local machine it's work fine, but on mobile emulator throws next exception:

> An exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException'
>   occurred in project.exe but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: ClassFactory cannot supply requested class
>   (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040111 (CLASS_E_CLASSNOTAVAILABLE))

[image]

StackTrace:

> - at System.StubHelpers.StubHelpers.GetWinRTFactoryObject(IntPtr    pCPCMD)
> - at Windows.Media.Playback.MediaPlayer..ctor()
> - at    Project.Services.PlaybackServiceFactory.Create(PlayerArgument arg)
> - at Project.ViewModels.PlayerViewModel..ctor(PlayerArgument arg)
> - at Project.MainPage.d__3.MoveNext()

All uwp examples with MediaPlayer also crashes. Previously it worked fine, whats maybe wrong? I would be glad of any help, thank you.

UPD: Problem actual for 10.0.10586 emulator version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [MediaPlayer constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.media.playback.mediaplayer.mediaplayer) is available from "Universal, introduced version 10.0.14393.0". So please run your project in 14393 emulator or grater.

You could [dynamically detect features with API contracts (10 by 10)](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2015/09/15/dynamically-detecting-features-with-api-contracts-10-by-10/)

> The Universal Windows Platform (UWP) allows you to write your app once and target multiple device families, while also taking advantage of new APIs introduced on later versions of the OS as well as using unique APIs only present on certain device families.

Comment: @Xavier-xie-msft does this mean if I use MediaPlayer it won't work in some phones ?

Comment: @Krishna Yes. As a result, you need to detect if the Apis were available in current environment.

Comment: @Xavier-xie-msft Got it, I saw the detection code, could you please let me know any equivalent code for media player initialization in 10.0.10586 ?